# How to add only one commit to a git tag

Tags: git, versioning, tagging

I have created a git tag, but then I made some other commits and one of those needs to be in the tag, the others do not.

For example:

```
git commit 123
git commit 456
git commit 789
git commit 1011
git commit 1213
```

I made a tag at point `1011`, but now I want to add commit `123` to that and not any of the ones in between. Any way to do that?

Comment: I'm not expert, but I believe a git tag is supposed to refer to a specific commit, so it would not make sense to have a tag that covers multiple commits. What are you hoping to accomplish with this tag?

Comment: I'm using it for a release, but need to add in that one recent commit.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand... A tag is for referring to commits, i.e. with `git checkout <tag>`. What would it mean to refer to two commits at once?

Comment: I believe a tag refers to a point in time of commits - all commits up to that point. I'm creating a release from a point in time and I want to add one bug fix essentially.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have your terminology mixed up.

- A tag is a string label attached to a single commit. It doesn't "contain" commits, it's just another way to name the commit that was tagged.
- A branch is a ordered set of commits, when you use `git commit` you'll add the commit to the current branch.

It's not clear if you just meant branch instead of tag, or if you're asking why the output of e.g. `git log mytag` is showing all commits since up until 1011.

`git log mytag` will log the commit tagged with `mytag` and all its parents.

If you meant branch and the branch you created does not yet contain commit 123 in it's history, you can `git cherry-pick` it.

Writing this, I realize you might also have meant how to add commit 123 to set of commits listed by `git log mytag`. To do that you need to create a new branch at that point, `git checkout -b mybranch mytag`, then cherry pick commit 123, then move the tag to the new commit, using `git tag -f`. Then you can go back to your previous branch (e.g. `git checkout master`). Your previous branch will then have a different history, the branches have diverged.

Comment: Yes, the last part of your answer is what I am trying to do - I need to make a new branch and cherry pick. Thank you!

Comment: "contains" is perfectly good terminology. It is common to say that a commit _contains_ an ancestor commit as the changes in the ancestor are included in the history of the containing commit. Similarly tag objects or lightweight tags can be said to contain the commits in their history, hence `git describe --contains`.

Answer (score 11):

Starting from your tag, you'll want to cherrypick the single commit you want to include. Then, you'll move your tag to point at the new state.

```
git checkout my_tag
git cherry-pick commit_123
git tag -f my_tag
```

It may help to think of tags as branches. Just like a branch, a tag refers to a particular point along a history of commits. So what you want to do is effectively create a new branch with a different commit history, then tag that new state. Checking out your current tag brings you back to the original point, cherrypicking pulls in the single commit you want to add, then retagging saves that new branch state. You'll need the `-f` option to "move" the tag otherwise you'll get a `tag 'my_tag' already exists` error.

Comment: Thanks. This might be a little easier. I will try that next time.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the changes are still local you should be able to squash the `1213` commit with `1011` and retag the squashed commit.